# Paypal return url countdown

Tags: url, paypal, return

I have setted paypal return url, after the payment start a countdowns of 10s and then the system open return url. can i avoid this countdown? can i return to my website immediately after payment? thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the very old HTML-only/redirect integration that uses no API, you cannot avoid the countdown. And if the payer pays with a card as a guest, PayPal may be legally obligated to show them a receipt before they return, meaning there will be no countdown and they must click to return.

So the only solution is to use a current SDK or API-based PayPal Checkout integration. [See the documentation here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/)